# Extjs keymap does not work with 6.5.1 modern

Tags: extjs

I use sencha extJs with Version 6.5.1 with the modern toolkit and I have the problem that the keyboard event handling with the keymap worked in the past and is now not working anymore.  I can't say since when exactly it doesn't work anymore, I only know that it definitely worked on October 14, 2020 and some time after that date. I use it as a parameter, for example on a dialog, like this:

```
   keyMap: {
        ENTER: {
           handler: function (e, view) {
              console.log("ENTER CLICKED");
           }
        }
     }
```

It doesn't work with the code base from October 14, so I think it is not a problem with my code. I can’t explain what circumstances caused it to stop working.

I have created a [example sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3cmp) with version 6.5.1 modern toolkit where it does not work, when you change the version to a classic 6.5.1, it works.

Do you have an idea what the problem is or can you help me make it work again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the dialog container is not having focus on opening, the keyboard events are not triggered. Make the container to get focus by setting focusable and tabIndex or on painted event set focus for any focusable controls in it.

```
            focusable: true, //required
            tabIndex: 1, //required
            keyMap: {
                A: {//65
                    scope: this,
                    //event: 'keydown',
                    handler: function () {
                        Ext.Msg.alert('key pressed', 'you have pressed a');
                        console.log("a pressed")
                    }
                },
                ENTER: { //13
                    scope: this,
                    //event: 'keypress',
                    handler: function () {
                        Ext.Msg.alert('key pressed', 'you have pressed enter');
                        console.log("enter pressed")
                    }
                }
            }
```

Check this out
[Keymap Fiddle viewer](https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/3cnk) / [Editor](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3cnk)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, that works. I am still wondering why it had worked in the past, but that is not important anymore.

Comment: Might be some issue with SDK try raise a ticket in customer forum..